# Typescript - how can I overload Array<MyType>::join() to return MyType instead of string?

Tags: typescript

I have a branded string type (e.g. `type MyType = string & { __brand: 'mytype' }`).

Is there a way I can declare an overload of `Array.join` for `Array<MyType>` that returns `MyType` instead of `string`?

Bonus points if the solution is generic and allows anything that extends, e.g. `Mergeable` to join to create a new instance of itself.

```
type Mergeable = string & { __mergeable: true }

type MyType = Mergeable & { __brand: 'MyType' }

const arr: MyType[] = ['a', 'b', 'c'] as any
const merged: MyType = arr.join(', ' as MyType)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wO21pW) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Definitely does. Behemoth seems to have posted it...

Comment: Yes, apparently.  ‍♂️

Comment: Could be a better answer if it were generic. E.g. applied to any type extending MyType and returned the actual type.

Comment: Like [this maybe](https://tsplay.dev/mMjjlW), but that looks out of scope for the question as asked

Comment: It's at least what I meant, if not what I asked. Certainly feels like it can be added to an answer to make it better than just answering the question alone.

Comment: You can [edit] the question to ask what you meant to ask, so that any such answer would be in scope.

Answer (score 2):

Since in TypeScript interfaces are [*merged*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces) together when declared multiple times you can add another declaration of `join()` that will be treated as an overload of the default `Array<T>.join()`.

> [**Merging Interfaces**](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces)
>
> The simplest, and perhaps most common, type of declaration merging is interface merging. At the most basic level, the merge mechanically joins the members of both declarations into a single interface with the same name. [...]
>
> For function members, each function member of the same name is treated as describing an overload of the same function.

```
type MyType = string & { __brand: 'mytype' }

interface Array<T> {
    join(this: Array<MyType>, separator?: MyType): MyType
}
```